# Как задать уровень изолированности для session.setAttribute() SpringBoot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, java-ee

session store type = jdbc
В общем, проблема в том, что иногда приходит 2 запроса с очень маленьким интервалом и setAttribute падает с ошибкой. Нужно запретить обновление данных в сессии пока выполняется предыдущий запрос.

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) SELECT PRIMARY_ID, ?, ? FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE SESSION_ID = ?]; Duplicate entry '6af53017-b1de-4a7c-b58d-89746aa73260-SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT' for key 'spring_session_attributes.PRIMARY'; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '6af53017-b1de-4a7c-b58d-89746aa73260-SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT' for key 'spring_session_attributes.PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:247) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.insertSessionAttributes(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:484) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.access$1200(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:131) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.lambda$save$10(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:820) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:802) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.access$200(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:634) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:410) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:131) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:225) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:192) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:144) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '6af53017-b1de-4a7c-b58d-89746aa73260-SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT' for key 'spring_session_attributes.PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Стектрейс добавлен

Comment: Это не стектрейс. Это только сообщение об ошибке. В стектрейсе видно в какой функции случилась ошибка, откуда та функция вызывалась, т.е. весь стек вызовов. Вот вы пишете `setAttribute падает с ошибкой`, и неясно какой `setAttribute`, у какого класса и т.д. А из stractrace это будет однозначно видно

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил стэктрейс